# RDP over VMBus does not work - troubleshooting tips?

Tags: multiple-monitors, remote-desktop, hyper-v

I have three monitors, and would like to use two of them for a VM, the third for the host.

With mstsc, this [is possible](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/how-to-remote-desktop-fullscreen-rdp-with-just-some-of-your-multiple-monitors) by editing the .rdp file.

With vmconnect, this isn't possible, multi-monitor is a boolean all-or-nothing.

I found [this article](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/data-center-security/connect-to-virtual-machines-vms-on-paw/ba-p/372286) which describes "RDP over VMBus", which should, in theory, be the best of both worlds.

Only it doesn't work.

I got my VM id by running `(get-vm "vmname").id`.

My .rdp file looks like this:

```
full address:s:localhost
server port:i:2179
pcb:s:3f6d3195-7aaf-40f3-a071-5b6e118cc7ba;EnhancedMode=1
```

When I right-click -> connect, it is stuck at "Configuring remote session...".

Any ideas?

I am running Windows 10 Pro x64 2004 on both Host and VM.

---

Edit:

I found [another article](https://thunderysteak.github.io/hyperv-direct-vm-rdp).

After adding the line `negotiate security layer:i:0`, it prompts me for credentials. when I enter the credentials for the host, I get:

[image]

---

If I then remove `;EnhancedMode=1`, I get a different error directly after login:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to [Enable enhanced console session in VMM](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/system-center/vmm/enhanced-console-session?view=sc-vmm-2019)?

Answer (score 0):

Hehe, I found [another random article](https://mremoteng.readthedocs.io/en/latest/howtos/vmrdp.html), this time not even about either mstsc or vmconnect, but a third-party product.

After adding my user to the **Hyper-V Administrators** group, it works.